# replace string values between two files

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want to replace the frequencies and bandwidths of formant [1] alone of the file 1 with the  frequencies and bandwidths of file 2 formant [1] .This replacement should be done for n frames.How to do this through a unix script as there are 1000 frames.Please help me out.

**file 1:**

```
frames []: 
    frames [1]:
        intensity = 0.006356559616564358 
        nFormants = 5 
        formant []: 
            formant [1]:
                frequency = 403.06628436252515 
                bandwidth = 160.21467462436982 
            formant [2]:
                frequency = 1507.54711702621 
                bandwidth = 519.232413949129 
            formant [3]:
                frequency = 2577.174907989416 
                bandwidth = 1535.5870557191413 
            formant [4]:
                frequency = 3764.624274996511 
                bandwidth = 209.668143917888 
            formant [5]:
                frequency = 4823.479775451361 
                bandwidth = 357.147764183363 
    frames [2]:
        intensity = 0.007108941260004555 
        nFormants = 5 
        formant []: 
            formant [1]:
                frequency = 420.7936179207871 
                bandwidth = 156.6697641580339 
            formant [2]:
                frequency = 1434.5440278308877 
                bandwidth = 377.849704303127 
            formant [3]:
                frequency = 2620.589627797242 
                bandwidth = 1336.5922989596068 
            formant [4]:
                frequency = 3772.337062263397 
                bandwidth = 248.2627364453784 
            formant [5]:
                frequency = 4748.112746186265 
                bandwidth = 244.23733261870277
```

**file 2:**

```
frames []: 
    frames [1]:
        intensity = 0.306356559616564358 
        nFormants = 5 
        formant []: 
            formant [1]:
                frequency = 203.06628436252515 
                bandwidth = 150.21467462436982 
            formant [2]:
                frequency = 1607.54711702621 
                bandwidth = 629.232413949129 
            formant [3]:
                frequency = 3577.174907989416 
                bandwidth = 3535.5870557191413 
            formant [4]:
                frequency = 4764.624274996511 
                bandwidth = 309.668143917888 
            formant [5]:
                frequency = 5823.479775451361 
                bandwidth = 457.147764183363 
    frames [2]:
        intensity = 0.007108941260004555 
        nFormants = 5 
        formant []: 
            formant [1]:
                frequency = 320.7936179207871 
                bandwidth = 156.6697641580339 
            formant [2]:
                frequency = 1334.5440278308877 
                bandwidth = 377.849704303127 
            formant [3]:
                frequency = 2520.589627797242 
                bandwidth = 1336.5922989596068 
            formant [4]:
                frequency = 4472.337062263397 
                bandwidth = 248.2627364453784 
            formant [5]:
                frequency = 4648.112746186265 
                bandwidth = 244.23733261870277
```

Comment: Are the file exactly the same length?  That is, they both have the same number of frames, same number of linesm and are identical except for the values of the data?

Comment: yes the files are of same length.Both have identical number of frames and lines.

Answer (score 0):

An awk oneliner (with your given assumptions):

```
awk '{lines[FILENAME,FNR]=$0;last=FNR}END{for(i=1;i<=last;i++){mod=(i-7+19)%19;print(lines[mod>1?"file1":"file2",i])}}' file1 file2
```

The breakdown is:

```
{
    lines[FILENAME,FNR]=$0;
    last=FNR
}
```

the above saves the lines for each file.  It also saves the FNR (file record number) so that it knows how many lines are in the file.

```
END {
    for(i=1;i<=last;i++) {
        mod=(i-7+19)%19;
        print(lines[mod>1?"file1":"file2",i])
    }
}
```

The above runs through each line, and prints the line from file 1 or 2, depending on the value of `mod`.  `mod` is computed to be every 19th line, starting at the 7th, which hits the formant[1] data for every frame.

Comment: How to change the mod value as some frames consists of only 4 formants and some frame consists of 5 formants.But the number of formants between file 1 and file 2 are same

Comment: My solution will only work if the files are the same number of lines/frames.  The formant line has to be consistently positioned throughout.

Comment: Thanks.But when i tried to save the values to a new file,the formant 1 frequency and band width values are emptyformant []: 
            formant [1]:


            formant [2]:
                frequency = 1507.54711702621 
                bandwidth = 519.232413949129 
            formant [3]:
                frequency = 2577.174907989416 
                bandwidth = 1535.5870557191413 
            formant [4]:
                frequency = 3764.624274996511 
                bandwidth = 209.668143917888

Comment: The values of formants and bandwidths from file 2 is not replaced with values of formants and bandwidths of file 1.Those rows are empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    {
        getline a <file2
        if(prn)
            print a
        else
            print
    }
    /formant \[1\]/{
        prn = 1
    }
    /bandwidth/{
        prn = 0
    }
    ' file1
```

For different numbers of formants in file1 and file2 to get just frequency:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
        pattern = "formant \\[1\\]"
    }
    prn{
        prn = 0
        while($0 !~ pattern)
            getline <file2
        getline <file2
    }
    $0 ~ pattern{
        prn = 1
    }
    1
    ' file1
```

Comment: How to modify the script if the file 1 frame 1 contains 5 formants but file 2 frame 1 contains  only 4 formants.But my requirement is to change frame 1 formant 1  frequency of file 1 with frame 1 formant 1frequency of file 2.

Comment: @santhan see added

Comment: the values are not replaced.Instead  the values in file2 is stored in file 3.

Comment: @santhan edited

Comment: I tried your following code awk '
    {
        getline a <file2
        if(prn)
            print a
        else
            print
    }
    /formant \[1\]/{
        prn = 1
    }
    /bandwidth/{
        prn = 0
    }
    ' file1  .But the problem is empty values are stored in new file like below example: formant []: 
            formant [1]:


            formant [2]:
                frequency = 2087.393844073415 
                bandwidth = 1566.4725787162577 
            How to rectify this ???

Comment: @santhan /formant \\[1\\]/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly higher level approach.  This uses shell scripting instead of `awk` scripting.  The `awk` solutions are very elegant.  I provide this as an alternative example.

Assumptions: there are the same number of formants, and the formants are in the same order in each file.  The first formant in file1 replaces the first formant in file2, 2nd format replaces 2nd format, etc.  The formants can contain a variable number of lines, and the number of lines per formant can be different in each file.

This script uses the `csplit` command to split each file into multiple parts.  The odd-numbered parts contain the `formant[1]`s, the even numbered parts contain everything else.

After splitting both files, Remove all of the odd-numbered parts from file2 and remove all the even numbered parts from file1.  Then `cat` the remaining files together to produce the final output.

Since we've modified the `csplit` output filename format, appending the file number to the end, both original files will be split into the same directory, and we utilize the shell's pattern matching and sorting to remove the appropriate files and re-assemble the remaining parts in the correct order.

```
#!/bin/sh

USAGE="
    $0: Usage: $0 file1 file2
    $0 replaces formant[1]'s in file1 with formant[1]'s from file2
    $0 prints the new version of file1 on standard output
"

TMP=tmp$$
mkdir $TMP

for i in 2 1
do
    csplit --quiet --prefix="$TMP/" --suffix-format="%09d-$i" "${1:?$USAGE}" \
         '/formant \[[12]\]/' '{*}'
    shift
done

rm $TMP/*[13579]-2
rm $TMP/*[02468]-1
cat $TMP/*
rm -r $TMP
```

This produces the same output as [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244161/139893)

Comment: Thanks for your update.i have certain queries.How to customise the above code in a generalised way such that I can change frequency of formant1 alone  not bandwidth.I have to do trail and error in order to find best performance by modifying formants 1 to 5 and bandwidths 1 to 5 separetely between two files

Comment: Thanks for your update.i have certain queries.How to customise the above code in a generalised way such that I can change frequency of formant1 alone  not bandwidth.I have to do trail and error in order to find best performance by modifying formants 1 to 5 and bandwidths 1 to 5 separetely between two files.(i.e) in first try i should try only replacing formant frequency alone not bandwidth.In second try i should try only replacing formant 1 and formant 2  frequency alone with bandwidth.I should try these above combinations.How to generalise

Comment: A detailed explanation is given in the follwing question "replacing values between two files using scripting"

Comment: I tried replacing the code so as to  generalise but when the frame size increases desired output is not obtained

Comment: Thanks for your update.i have certain queries.How to customise the above code in a generalised way such that I can change frequency of formant1 alone not bandwidth.I have to do trail and error in order to find best performance by modifying formants 1 to 5 and bandwidths 1 to 5 separetely between two files.(i.e) in first try i should try only replacing formant frequency alone not bandwidth.In second try i should try only replacing formant 1 and formant 2 frequency alone with bandwidth.I should try these above combinations.How to generalise

Comment: You want to manage different sets of frequencies and bandwidths?  Will the frequencies and/or bandwidths always be used within the same formant?  Will all formants be updated or only certain formant numbers per file?  Would something like this work?:  `generate.sh original-file [-f frequency-file]  [-b bandwidth-file] [formantnum ...]`   If `-f frequency-file` is given, then all frequencies in `frequency-file` replace frequencies in `original-file`.  Same for bandwidths.  Process all formants unless `formantnum`s are given. Executing `generate.sh original` prints the input file unmodified.

Comment: I want to replace only   1. F1 (Formant frequency [1]) alone ) from file 1 to (Formant frequency [1]) from file 2.     2.F1 and F2 (Formant frequency [1]) alone ) from file 1 to F1 and F2 (Formant frequency [1]) from file 2.  3.F1 and B1 from file 1 to F1 and B1 to file2 4.F1,B1,F2 and B2 form file 1 and file 2.....likewise i want to check for F3 alone ,F1 F2 and F3 replacement all combinations..